# select records that add up to a number

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have a table that looks like this
Table - mylist

```
-----
id | max_p 
----------
1   | 4  
2   | 2   
3   | 2   
4   | 6  
5   | 2    
6   | 2
```

I'd like to run a query which will find the minimum number of rows where the sum of max_p=10. so in this instance it would select records 1 and 4

if I wanted to run the same query to find 12 then it would select records 1,4 and 5

if I wanted to find records which equalled 2 it would just select record number 5 as that is the correct number and therefore no more than one record needs to be selected?

ideally this would select just one record if the desired amount was the same as any one row, then if this wasn't possible it would select two records, then three etc. If the desired number wasn't possible then it would return an empty result

fiddle here : http://ideone.com/3ECaT2

```
CREATE TABLE  `my_list` (
  `id` int(2) ,
  `max_p` int(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;


INSERT INTO `my_list` (`id`, `max_p`) VALUES
(1, 4),
(2, 2),
(3, 2),
(4, 6),
(5, 2),
(6, 2);
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: retrieve the whole data set, and do it on the client side...

Answer (score 2):

To really solve this problem in SQL, you would need recursive subqueries.  MySQL does not offer this functionality.  What you can do is look for such a combination with up to a given number of elements.  The following query implements this for four combinations:

```
select ml1.max_p as p1, ml2.max_p as p2, ml3.max_p as p3, ml4.max_p as p4
from my_list ml1 left outer join
     my_list ml2
     on ml1.id < ml2.id left outer join
     my_list ml3
     on ml2.id < ml3.id left outer join
     my_list ml4
     on ml3.id < ml4.id
where coalesce(ml1.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml2.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml3.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml4.max_p, 0)
```

To get the shortest, count the number of elements and use `limit`:

```
select ml1.max_p as p1, ml2.max_p as p2, ml3.max_p as p3, ml4.max_p as p4
from my_list ml1 left outer join
     my_list ml2
     on ml1.id < ml2.id left outer join
     my_list ml3
     on ml2.id < ml3.id left outer join
     my_list ml4
     on ml3.id < ml4.id
where coalesce(ml1.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml2.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml3.max_p, 0) + coalesce(ml4.max_p, 0)
order by ((ml1.map_p is null) +
          (ml2.map_p is null) +
          (ml3.map_p is null) +
          (ml4.map_p is null)
         ) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: +1 quite neat. Except for the formatting of course :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. When I try to run either of the queries I get an error saying " Not unique table/alias: 'ml2'" 
Apologies for being such a newbie